# Unable to send sms programatically in android

Tags: android, smsmanager

Hi i am a new android developer.i am trying to send sms through android built-in service 
SmsManager class my code is running accurately but the message sent through this is not received to other number.My code is as follows

```
      btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String ph=et1.getText().toString();
            String text=et2.getText().toString();
            try{
            SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(ph,null, text,null,null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message not sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: is there any warning or error in your logcat? can you post logcat when on button click ?

Comment: 09-21 03:22:49.507: E/CellLocation(11428): create GsmCellLocation
this exception is shown in logcat

Comment: after i have selected my first sim as default the problem was solved.it was because of confusion of dual sim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please check following permission

  android.permission.SEND_SMS

Answer (score 1):

This works perfect in my application

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    sendSMS("YOURNUMBER", Integer.toString(scaleFactor));
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sending msg...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    }
});

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

and in Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: still it is not working for me can you plz tell me is there any need of specific format for phone number??

Comment: In my application i tested it sending msg to my own number. I put my 10digit mobile number of india and it works

Comment: And when i check in my phone msges i.e googlehangouts . there were 2 logs .. 1 sending the msg and 2nd the received same msg

Comment: Does it require to have money in main balance of network provider?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a permission? android.permission.SEND_SMS ? You must add it if you want to send messages.
Try this code: http://blogs.wrox.com/article/sending-sms-messages-programmatically-in-your-android-application/